# Repeated samples of multiple draws without replacement between draws or samples

Tags: random, sampling

We have a urn containing $N$ marbles of $m$ colours, i.e. $N = \sum_{i=1}^{m} K_i$.

If we draw $n$ marbles from the urn without replacement, the probability that we have a specific distribution $(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m)$ (where $n = \sum_{i=1}^{m}k_i$) is given by the multivariate hypergeometric distribution:

$$
P(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m) = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\binom{K_i}{k_i}}{\binom{N}{n}} 
$$

What happens if i then take additional draws without replacing the marbles removed by the first draw?

I know conditional probability can be used if we assume that the first draw was the same composition as the second draw as we know the composition of what we removed in the first draw, i.e.

$$
P((k_1,k_2, ..., k_m),(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m)) = P(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m) \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\binom{K_i-k_i}{k_i}}{\binom{N-n}{n}} = \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\binom{K_i}{k_i}}{\binom{N}{n}}\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{m}\binom{K_i-k_i}{k_i}}{\binom{N-n}{n}}
$$

What I really want is the probability that sample $j$ consisting of $n$ draws without replacement from the urn will be of composition $(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m)$ but so that I can use it to compute a bulk property. If I was just looking for the single sample we could re-arrange so that sample $j$ is sample 1 and just use a hypergeometric.

I have a function $f(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m)$ that computes a scalar property from the sample and so I want to compute the expected value of $f$ when we exhaustively sample the urn:

$$
\hat{f} = \sum f(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m)\hat{Z}(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m)
$$

Where $\hat{Z}$ is the expected number of draws of composition $(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m)$ which I am assuming is going to be $\frac{N}{n}P'(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m)$ where $P'$ is the probability I am after.

(and if that turns out to be the multivariate hypergeometric distribution too that's fine... but I would need to know why it is valid as intuitively to me that doesn't seem correct)

## Update

Here are some examples:

If we have an urn with 3 red, 5 blue and 4 green marbles

The sum for $\hat f$ when the sample size is 4 will need to consider $(3,1,0)$, $(3,0,1)$, $(2,2,0)$, $(2,1,1)$, $(2,0,2)$, $(1,3,0)$, $(1,2,1)$, $(1,1,2)$, $(1,0,3)$, $(0,4,0)$, $(0,3,1)$, $(0,2,2)$, $(0,1,3)$, $(0,0,4)$

In the case of $(2,1,1)$ only one sample of 4 per emptying of the urn can match because once 2 red marbles have been removed there is only 1 red marble remaining in the urn

In the case of $(1,2,1)$ at most two samples of 4 in any given emptying of the urn can match. An emptying of the urn that has two of the three emptyings matching $(1,2,1)$ will contribute twice to $\hat f$ in the brute force evaluation

Comment: If it helps to get an answer, I am really most interested in the three color problem (red, blue, green). An urn with say 1 million marbles and sampling 10 draws at a time. $f$ is only a function of the number or red and blue in the sample. What is the expected average value of f from an exhaustive sampling of 100000 samples of 10 marbles until there are none left in the urn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution is the same for every draw.  (I'm assuming that the number $n$ of items in a draw divides the total number $N$ of items.)  Imagine that the $N$ items are drawn one at time, without replacement, and placed in a line.  What is the probability that items $kn+1$ through $k(n+1)$ have composition $(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m)$?  Obviously this is just a random selection of $n$ of the $N$ items.

Therefore the average value of $f$ on any draw of $n$ marbles is $$A := \frac{n!(N-n)!}{N!}\sum f(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m)\binom{K_1}{k_1}\binom{K_2}{k_2}\cdots\binom{K_m}{k_m}$$ where the sum is over all compositions $k_1+k_2+\cdots+ k_m=n$.

Since we are drawing without replacement, top compute the probability of the composition $(k_1,\dots k_m)$ we want the number of ways to to pick $k_1$ items from  $K_1$, $k_2$ from $K_2$, and so on, divided by the number of ways to pick $n$ items from $N$.

We make $\left\lfloor\frac Nn\right\rfloor$ draws, so the expected value of $f$ on all the draws is $$\left\lfloor\frac Nn\right\rfloor A$$

Although, as indicated in the update, the outcome of a draw of $n$ items is dependent on the prior draws, we are only concerned with the expected value, and expectation is linear, even if the random variables are dependent, so we can simply add up the expectations of all the draws.

Comment: I don't think this is correct as it does not include the population levels of each type: $K_1,K_2,...,K_m$ only the numbers in each sample, i.e. $N=K_1+K_2+...+K_m$ also

Comment: Did you mean:
$$\frac{n!(N-n)!}{N!}\sum_{k_1+k_2+...+k_m=n} \left ( f(k_1,k_2, ..., k_m)\binom n{k_1,k_2, ..., k_m}\prod_{i=1}^{m} {\left (  \frac {K_i} {N}\right )^{k_i}} \right )$$

where $\frac {K_i}{N}$ is the probability that any one marble chosen in a single random draw is of type $i$ ?

Comment: I was wrong, but I think you are, too.  I'll edit it.

Comment: Testing your logic: we expect there to be $$
\frac{\binom {K_1}{k_1}\binom {K_2}{k_2}...\binom {K_m}{k_m}}{\binom {N}{n}}$$ of all $N!$ permutations... however I did some brute-force checks:

With 3xA, 5xB and 4xC, for a full brute force of all 12! combinations I counted 348364800 out of 479001600 groups of 4 letters with 1 A, 2 B's and 1 C which is 3x more than the formula.

I counted 174182400 groups of 4 letters with 2 A's, 1 B and 1 C which is again 3x more than the formula.

Comment: I also did a brute force with 3xA, 1xB and 4xC and that counted 13824 sequences of 2 A's, 1 B and 1 C in any order from all 40320 permutations (and yes there are duplicates in the permutations because I'm just brute forcing the string of letters and ignoring the fact that there is repetition because repetition will wash out in both. That is 2x the expected from the formula

I am suspecting the formula may need a factor of at least $\frac {N}{n}$ to correct for the potential of the sequence occuring in any of the $N/n$ draws

Comment: I also worry that the $\frac {N}{n}$ factor is just small numbers and the true factor is different for larger urn sizes

Comment: @StephenConnolly I don't understand what calculation you are doing.  There are only $288$ permutations of $4$ items chosen from $8$.  I did the brute-force calculation in your next-to-last comment with both permutations and combinations combinations and got $\frac{288}{1680}$ and $\frac{12}{70}$, as expected.  This is half what you got, so you're  of by a factor of $3!$

Comment: There are 288 permutations of the *first* four chosen from 8 but the second four can also match from what I can see. I generated all 8! Rearrangements of AAABCCCC (which includes 3!4! duplicates of each because I’m brute forcing and treating each letter as unique in the permutation code) I then count in each 8 letter sequence how many of the first 4 plus how many in the second 4

Comment: @StephenConnolly Your question says, "If we draw $n$ marbles from the urn ...".  You should only look at the first $n$ items in the permutation.  Or the second through the $n+1$th.  Or any $n$ chosen in advance.

Comment: > If I was just looking for the single sample we could re-arrange so that sample  is sample 1 and just use a hypergeometric.

I was trying to make it clear that I need all $j$ samples of $n$ draws until the urn is empty

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve says if we get the arrangement in the 1st $n$ and the 5th $n$ and the 43rd $n$ then that emptying of the urn in batches of $n$ returned three matches and thus that emptying constributes 3 $f$ towards $\hat f$ in contrast to an emptying that only matches the arrangement in the 34th batch of $n$ marbles... out of the total $N!$ possible emptyings of the urn

Comment: Okay.  I didn't understand this from the question.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: That looks correct but can you just confirm against my update to the question before I accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.  Let me add a little more detail to the answer though.  Now that I see your update, I think I know what the essential point of the question is.